# Get disk usage from SoftLayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am creating a script for monitoring our virtual servers using the SoftLayer API.

I am able to get the current disk space by getting the `blockDevice` and associated `diskImage` for each virtual server, as specified [here](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Disk_Image), but how can I get the used/free space on each block device, so I can compute the percent of space available?

Here is how I'm currently fetching the data:

```
$server = SoapClient::getClient("SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest", $id, $username, $apikey);
$server->setObjectMask("mask[maxCpu,maxCpuUnits,maxMemory,statusId,status[keyName],bandwidthAllocation,billingCycleBandwidthUsage[amountOut,type],metricTrackingObjectId,billingItem[recurringMonths,nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount],datacenter[name,longName],blockDevices[statusId,status[keyName],diskImage[capacity,typeId,type[keyName],units]]]");
$server_data = $server->getObject();
```

The problem is that the various block devices only hold a reference to the disk images, which in turn have a `capacity` field, but nothing that seems to link to the actual used space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry that information is not stored in softlayer database, you only can see the disk usage from image templates, but from provisioned servers there is not such information.

Regards